# Getting latest row in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I need to filter my user info and return only latest row.

## Code

`Blade`

```
@foreach($users as $user)

    //user data
    @foreach($user->invoices as $invoice)
        {{$invoice->type->name}}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

This returns all user invoices I need to filter and get latest one only.

## Issue

I know I am able to get latest row by `first()` in controller but as this data is in my users page (showing all users) that's not possible for me to loop my users in my controller, I need get that `first` action in blade.

`Controller`

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();

    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: User::last() can be used

Comment: @Learner in where? I don't use `User` my users are looped

Comment: So you want latest invoice? Or what?

Comment: @Learner yes!..

Comment: `$user->inovices->latest()` or `$user->inovices()->latest()`

Comment: @Learner `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I used code below and it shows my latest row now

```
{{$user->invoices->last()->type->name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get latest inovice you can do this:

```
$user->inovices->latest() or $user->inovices()->latest()
```

**Method latest() orders all rows by created_at desc, and takes the first one.**

If that doesnt work you can:

User.php model:

```
public function latestInovice() {
    return $this->hasOne(Inovice::class)->latest();
}
```

And then use:

```
$users = User::with(['latestInovice'])->get();
```